# Creating a token with encryption

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption

I am using a rails api for the backend of my iphone app. Users need to be able to sign in so on the rails side I am creating a remember_token, sending this back to the app in a header, and encrypting the token on the rails side. From then on, whenever a post request is made from the app, it sends the token with it. For things like creating a photo on the app, I need to find the user sending the request. To do this, I am using what is listed bellow. The problem is that the remember_token being sent to the phone is different from the one being saved to rails. For example: One save to phone:`CknQijl5EcaPEWUP_pX4Rw` Token saved to user on rails: `e18f05d5e7260cc70dde4e68c590dde4bd2d2b04`

Here is how I create the token:

```
def User.new_remember_token
  SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end

def User.hash(token)
  Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
end
```

When a user is created or signed in:

```
remember_token = User.new_remember_token
@user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.hash(remember_token))
response.headers['X-TOKEN'] = remember_token
```

Finding the user through the token when needed:

```
@key = request.headers['X-TOKEN']
@user = User.find_by_remember_token(@key)
```

Error message:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
app/models/school.rb:21:in `follow!'
app/controllers/api/v1/schools_controller.rb:21:in `create'
```

Comment: The error is related to the the `school` model being `nil` and therefor not having an id.  Are you including that as evidence that the `user` is nil so it isn't finding the school?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are calling `User.hash` in the `update_attributes` method, but setting the response header to the `remember_token` variable.  You need to hash the `remember_token` and store it in the `remember_token` variable before the `update_attributes` call.

```
remember_token = User.hash(User.new_remember_token)
@user.update_attribute(:remember_token, remember_token)
response.headers['X-TOKEN'] = remember_token
```